# How did European monarchies become nation states?

Tags: europe

I have a pretty specific question.

How did European monarchies become nation states?

Can someone give me some good examples? My history book is kind of vague.

Comment: What does your preliminary research tell you?

Comment: You might want to review [Westphalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_of_Westphalia) and the [French Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Revolution) both referenced in [Nation State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation_state)

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close because the development of the nation state is subtle and H:SE is very good at summarizing subtle information into coherent pithy threads.  That said, OP should consider demonstrating prior research and asking specific questions about which dots need connecting.  What is it about the development of Nation States that is vague and confusing? How do you understand it to happen? What do you believe are the critical distinctions between a monarchy and a nation state?

Comment: I would say that the revolts of 1848 were the main event for most european countries, because that creates parlaments in many countries.

Answer (score 0):

A number of concurrent technical and organizational developments contributed.  During true feudal times the loyalty/fealty chain ran from serf to his local lord (nobility) who, in turn, pledged fealty to the sovereign.  This arrangement started to crack with the revolution in communication (printing) that enabled a more or less erudite serfdom to become an aware and skill bourgeois craftsman/tradesman.  Louis IV took advantage of the situation to entice his nobility to Versailles while replacing the local government with skilled commoners and ad hoc nobility.  As a result nationalism displaced more fragmented local governance.  France became a nation state.  A nation state that a few years later saw no need for royalty.

Nationalism presented problems for the royal empire.   Areas of Influence became nationalistic and sought autonomy.  Royalty and colonialists sought to hold onto their old territories.  Think Serbia and the Kaiser.  Nationalism is the result of and the driving force for a nation state.